# Adding items to a list dynamically in a recyclerview and copying to a list in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm adding items to a list in a Recyclerview Adapter via an input dialog. when a user enters a value in a textfield and clicks on submit button, I want the entered value to be added to a list which is declared public in a fragment such that if I go to the fragment and click on *showListSize* button, I should see the size of the list(in fragment) being greater than 0;

Adding an item to the list in RecyclerView works but the size cannot exceed 1. What could I be doing wrong.

Here is a sample code:

```
//Adapter, constructor and variables declaration
//on create viewholder


 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    List<Item2> valuesList = new ArrayList<Item2>(child.get(groupname));
    childSize = valuesList.size();

    Log.i("List size", String.valueOf(childSize));

    if (childSize > 0){
        //final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,position);

        final Item2 item = valuesList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(item.getItemName());
        //holder.itemImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(item.getImageUrl()));

        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
             
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.select_quantity);

                Button button_submit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                final EditText edQuantity = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
                edQuantity.setText("0");

                button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    float totalPrice = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String quantity = edQuantity.getText().toString();
       
                        totalPrice = Float.parseFloat(quantity) * Float.parseFloat(item.getPrice());

                        myLocal.add(new CartItem(quantity, item.getItemName(), item.getPrice(),String.valueOf(totalPrice)));

                        AllProducts myProducts = new AllProducts(); //this is the fragment

                        myProducts.theSelected.add(new CartItem(quantity,item.getItemName(), item.getPrice(),String.valueOf(totalPrice)));
                             
                      Log.i("size(Recycler)",String.valueOf(myProducts.theSelected.size())); //this is ok returns 1

                     dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
```

**AllProducts fragment**

```
public List<CartItem> theSelected = new ArrayList<CartItem>();//list declaration

 btnShowListSize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            Log.i("list(AllProducts)", String.valueOf(theSelected.size()));//returns 0
        }
    });
```

Comment: AllProducts myProducts = new AllProducts(); this is the wrong way to add item in list.
its creating a new instance every time. that's why you found 1 item in list every time.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar I thought it is a way of accessing a list variable in AllProducts. Anyways how can I do it? sample code...

Comment: define it at global level or Make fragment as single instance.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar defining it at global level worked. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined a global ArrayList like this

```
private List<Items> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then a method to add items, still in global class

```
public void addItems(Item item) {
        this.selectedItems.add(item);
    }
```

Then in a class somewhere in the project:

```
final Globals myGlobals = Globals.getInstance();

Item myItem = new Item("var1", "var2", "var3");

myGlobals.addItems(myItem);
```